# Application sharing by Extending the group ID extractor in WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to use custom group Id extractor by extending "NewPostLoginExecutor" interface. 
I have followed the steps given in -> [Application Sharing](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/manage-application/sharing-applications/sharing-applications/#enabling-application-sharing). 
I have added the OSGI compatible JAR in "<APIM_HOME>/resources/components/lib". 
When I start the APIM server, I am getting the following error while server startup -> [image]

Do let me know if anyone has faced similar issue and what could be the possible solution!!

**Updated** -> 
Configuration added in deployment.toml file -> 
[apim.devportal] 
url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal" 
enable_application_sharing = true 
application_sharing_impl = "com.test.group.extension.ExecutorServiceImpl"

New class implemented ->

```java
@Service
public class ExecutorServiceImpl implements NewPostLoginExecutor {
    
    @Override
    public String getGroupingIdentifiers(String response) {
         \\My implementation
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getGroupingIdentifierList(String loginResponse){
         \\My implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the configs that you have added? Also, mention the class name of your custom `NewPostLoginExecutor` that you have implemented?

Comment: @SomindaGamage I have included configuration changes and the class I have implemented in my updated question.

Comment: Can you check whether you have another event adapter with the same name in the error trace?
Also if the bundle is an OSGi bundle you can try adding it to the dropins directory

Comment: @SomindaGamage Thanks, I checked and the issue was due to the Logger I was using in my implemented method. Just a follow-up question on this, how can I package external libraries with my build ? I am trying to use ClientBuilder and for that I am getting the following error ->  ERROR - [CXFServlet] Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path [/api/am/devportal] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found by JAR_FILE_NAME.

Comment: you can pack with your bundle or add to `dropins` or `libs`. Better to check whether the product has these jar versions packed already. If so better to use those versions.